# Failed to load map with markers in android 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I have developed an android application with a map displaying markers on it with some information (requires android 4.0.3 and up).

Before releasing it I tested my app in most of the android OSs from 4.0.3 to 5 and I didn't face any issues.Today I tried to install my released app (from play store) in a tablet device with NEXUS 7 google and android verion 5.1.1. The app does not load my map at all message displayed "Application Stopped".

I tried an older private version of my app (in debug mode) in NEXUS 7 tablet and it was success with the only difference that I do not display toast messages. Toast message indicates if connection is available or not in user's device. This message is displayed on user's screen when map is loaded in order to inform user if connected or not to the internet. Please find below the code:

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    //mobile
    NetworkInfo.State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();

    //wifi
    NetworkInfo.State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();


    if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Is the problem I had really related to the toast? Is the NEXUS 7 device blocking any try of connectivity manager to read the state of wi-fi or 3G from the device? So is the problem related to the security configuration applied on the device? Could you please help me to resolve this?

UPDATE CODE:

```
    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 if (conMan != null) {
//mobile
    NetworkInfo.State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();

//wifi
NetworkInfo.State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();


if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
} // end if
else 
{  //do nothing
}
```

Comment: Please take a look in the logcat and post the relevant output

Answer (score 0):

Add null checks for `conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)` and `conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)`, `getNetworkInfo` return null if connection type is not supported by the device.

From API Doc

> a NetworkInfo object for the requested network type or null if the type is not supported by the device.

What I am guessing is Nexus 7 doesn't support sim card due to that it can throw NullPointerException.

Comment: Could you please check new code "UPDATE CODE" with null check. Do you mean this? Is it correct?